# The layout structure can not show all the content in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

This is a custom row view of a listview, there is three content for each row, a thumbnail, a name and the point. Thumbnail should be align left while the point should align right, the name is the padding left , around 10 dp of the thumbnail.

The problem is , if I  follow the below design , and the name is too long, then I can not see the point, how to fix it? thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well what you like to happen? Do you want the name to be truncated? Would you like it to wrap to multiple lines? Would you care to include a screenshot of the current behavior to make it easier to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Perfer to wrap to multiple lines , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `ListView` item's layout, you can follow this layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:text="Point"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the point is at the different line . it should at the right and at the same line of the @+id/name , also it should align parent right

Comment: then would you like to `ellipsize` the `TextView` with id `@+id/name`? and fixed the length of that `TextView`?

Comment: yes, it is okay for trim the extra data , it would be better if it trim base on the screen width.

Comment: See my updated answer...I think this time you will meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pts"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```